# Isomorphism from natural isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

Let $F,G: A \to B$ be two functors that are naturally isomorphic. Can I conclude that there is a isomorphism $H$ between $A$ and $B$? (in the sense $H^{-1}H(A) = 1_A$)

I don't think that this is possible. But I don't know if the natural condition can change things. If it is not possible, can I add more conditions to ensure that will exist a isomorphism?

Comment: This is very, very strongly not true. Pick any non-isomorphic categories $A, B$ and any functor $F : A \to B$. Then $F$ is naturally isomorphic to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Here $F$ and $G$ are functors from a category $A$ to a category $B$. We can look at the category $\text{Fun}(A,B)$ of functors from $A$ to $B$, and a natural isomorphism is saying that $F$ and $G$ are isomorphic as objects of this functor category.

Asking if there is an isomorphism between $A$ and $B$ as categories would be asking for a pair of functors $H: A \to B$ and $H^{-1} : B \to A$ so that $H^{-1} \circ H$ is the identity functor on $A$, and $H \circ H^{-1}$ is the identity functor on $B$. Usually this is asking too much (it's too [strict](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+category)) so we ask for [equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories) between $A$ and $B$ instead. That is, we ask for $H \circ H^{-1}$ and $H^{-1} \circ H$ to be merely isomorphic to the identity functors, rather than equal on-the-nose.

Either way, knowing that $F$ and $G$ are naturally isomorphic functors from $A$ to $B$ tells us nothing about isomorphism or equivalence of $A$ and $B$. For instance, any [adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) $L \dashv R$ between categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ gives rise to the natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(L-,-) \cong \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,R-)$ as functors $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{D} \to \mathsf{Set}$, but $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{D}$ is almost never isomorphic or equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}$.

If you want to guarantee an isomorphism between two categories, you'll probably have a hard time. If an equivalence is good enough, you'll either want information about functors going *both* ways (that is, you should have a functor $F : A \to B$ and a functor $G : B \to A$ that you expect are inverses) or you'll want to use the famous theorem that $F : A \to B$ is an equivalence if and only if it's fully faithful and "essentially surjective" (surjective up to isomorphism). See the "alternative characterizations" section of the wikipedia article for equivalences I linked earlier.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks! That help me. Special thanks to the "both ways" and "equivalence" intuition.